# Basic forwarding on Ubuntu not working

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking

I have the following setup, minimized to explain the problem:

```
                                 _________      
                                 |Desktop |    
                                 ----------     
                          192.168.2.6|               
                                     |              
                                     |              
                                 ------------          |------------------
                   --------------| Switch   |          |  Firewall server
                   |             ------------          |------------------
                   |192.168.2.110                          |         |
           ----------------                    192.168.1.11|         |To ISP
           |   Server     |---------------     ------------|         |------------
           ---------------- 192.168.1.121      |          
                                       |       |
                                      ------------
                                      |  Switch  |
                                      ------------
```

I have set default gateway on Desktop to 192.168.2.110

I have set default gateway on Server  to 192.168.1.11

I have forwarding enabled on Server and Firewall server

I can ping from Desktop to Server and vice-versa

I can ping from Server to Firewall server and vice-versa.

I can ping from Desktop to 192.168.1.121 too.

**I cannot ping from Desktop to Firewall server 192.168.1.11.**
   I tried with all iptables rules flushed on all the machines shown.
   What am I missing?

EDIT: To provide more information, as requested. ALL machines are running Linux Ubuntu. The desktops are development machines. The server runs development servers... Mysql, PhP, Apache, etc. The Firewall server has a set of iptables rules which I disable when testing ping just to get to it.

Comment: This may sound obvious but, have you enable forwarding on "server"?

Comment: @Xavy Yes! As stated in my post: "I have forwarding enabled on Server and Firewall server"  I am really stumped here... please see if there is anything else obvious that I am missing. I had a similar experimental setup earlier which worked with NAT on server. I do not think I need NAT on server when there is one already on Firewall server.

Comment: Not enough information. You say 'Server': what software are you running there? Looks like a router to me. Double NAT? How will 'server' forward packets?  Using iptables'? (just enabling the Kernel not enough)  Do you have internet access from 'Server'? please edit your post.

Comment: @Fcm Please see updates. I suspect that I need to add routes on the desktop to reach 192.168.1.11 and set the default gateway to 192.168.1.11. There are no express routes set on any machines at this time. I thought just forwarding would do...

Comment: 'server' is the only route for 'desktop', so, no routes needed. At the same time, once the packages arrives to 'server' knows where to find 192.168.1.11. However, the other way around is not that clear. 'Bangal' jump ahead with the, what I think, is the right answer: give 'firewall' visibility to your 192.168.2,0/24 network.

Comment: @Fcm Thanks for your help. You are correct, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a route for the `192.168.2.0/24` network in your firewall. It should be something like:

```
route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 gw 192.168.1.121
```

Your firewall has no idea where to send a packet when it is coming from 192.168.2.0/24 network. The server can ping the firewall because it is directly connected over 192.168.1.121.

Actually, when you try to reach the firewall from the desktop, the packet is arriving at the firewall (given that the server also has default gw set to firewall ip 192.168.1.11) but the firewall can't send it back to the desktop, as there is no route for this network available. And it can only forward the packets to the default gateway to the ISP, which will be discarded at the end.

Comment: Perfect! It works!  I just copied your command after making appropriate address changes to fit my actual IP addresses and tried because it makes 100% sense. However, I use the "ip" command and will try to delete the route added and add the route using that command.  Not that it matters how the route is added but thats what we use in all shell scripts...  THANKS A LOT... was very frustrating...

Comment: @Sam, You are welcome and glad that it worked.